# Refresh only an UpdatePanel inside another UpdatePanel

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, updatepanel

If there is `UpdatePanel` inside another `UpdatePanel`, and in the inner UpdatePanel there is a button, I want when clicking this button, only refresh the inner `UpdatePanel`. how ?

Answer (score 5):

IN the innerupdate panel set the updatemode to conditional and set the outerupdatepanel childrenastriggers property to false. In the inner update panel add a postbacktrigger and set it to the button which will cause the postback. Something like this

```
  <asp:UpdatePanel ID="parentup" runat="server" ChildrenAsTriggers="false">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="chidlup" UpdateMode="Conditional" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:Button ID="btn" runat="server" />
            </ContentTemplate>
            <Triggers>
                <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="btn" />
            </Triggers>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Answer (score 4):

*@Waqar Janjua* is right.

But you don't have to set the ChildrenAsTriggers to false, sometimes it is more convenient to leave it as true.

Set in both of your updatepanels the attribute **UpdateMode="Conditional"** (leave the ChildrenAsTriggers as its default true). then between the:  to the  add the trigger to your button as Janjua said:

```
<Triggers>
    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btn" />
</Triggers>
```

When the UpdateMode is not conditional each updatepanel would update it.

Answer (score 0):

This code helps you:Here is `Source`

```
 <asp:ScriptManager ID="script1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="up1" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblTime" runat="server" ForeColor="Red"></asp:Label>
                <asp:Button ID="buttonOuter" runat="server" OnClick="buttonOuter_Click" Text="What is the time?" />
                <asp:UpdatePanel ID="up2" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                    <ContentTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblTime2" runat="server" ForeColor="Blue"></asp:Label>
                        <asp:Button ID="buttonInner" runat="server" OnClick="buttonInner_Click" Text="What is the time?" />
                    </ContentTemplate>
                </asp:UpdatePanel>
            </ContentTemplate>
            <Triggers>
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger  ControlID="buttonOuter" EventName="Click"/>
            </Triggers>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

And here is `code behinde`:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
protected void buttonInner_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    up2.Update();
    lblTime2.Text = DateTime.Now.Second.ToString();
}
protected void buttonOuter_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lblTime.Text = DateTime.Now.Second.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If UP1 is the outer UpdatePanel , and UP2 is the inner, and you want to prevent the outer to be updated with inner's Button(for exp:Btn):

```
UP1.UpdateMode="Conditional"
UP1.ChildrenAsTriggers= "False"
```

Also you **shouldn't** add the Btn as a Trigger in UP1(like The following code)

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UP1" runat="server" ....>
   <ContentTemplate>
    ....
   </ContentTemplate>
  <Triggers>
   <asp:Trigger ControlID="btn" EventName="Click"/>
  </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```